# Стоит ли делать анимации переходов между анимациями для игрового персонажа?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Здравствуйте. Задался таким вопросом, а стоит ли делать к примеру анимацию перехода из состояния спокойствия в бег, и другие подобные анимации? Я просто не знаю, умеет ли юнити сам плавно переключать анимации, и может ли он анимацию бега  начать с одной ноги, если анимация бега начинается сразу с двух ног?

Comment: unity умеет сам плавно переключать анимации. но только не покадровые. посетите официальное руководство об анимациях в unity

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите информацию по `Mecanim`(это механизм стейт машин для анимации в юнити), благо документация уже почти вся на русском. Смешивание анимации присутствует, надо повозиться поразбираться, но это того стоит. Если с головой то данный функционал можно использовать много где.

Answer (score 0):

В юнити есть встроенный "сливатор" анимаций для плавности, в аниматоре нажми на стрелку перехода и двигай кривые анимаций в инспекторе для сливания

Comment: по русски подойдет слово смешивание больше)